# Pragma optimize for specific type of template function

Tags: c++, optimization, compiler-optimization

How to apply optimization 'off' [flag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/optimize?view=vs-2017) only for a specific type in template function?

Comment: Doesn't look like you can.

Comment: If you have a specific type, you can try specializing your function for it and enclose this specialization in `pragma`.